# Expand with a Taylor formula $\frac{2+x}{x^2+2x+2}$ near the $x_0 = -1$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am not sure whether I am doing it correctly. So,

$$\frac{2+x}{x^2+2x+2} = \frac{2}{x^2+2x+2} + \frac{x}{x^2+2x+2} = F_1 + F_2,$$
$$x^2+2x+2 = (x - x_1)(x-x_2), \text{where} \\ x_1 = i+1, \\x_2 = i -1;$$
$$F_1 = \frac{2}{(x - x_1)(x-x_2)} = \frac{A}{(x - x_1)} + \frac{B}{(x - x_2)} = \frac{1}{(x - i - 1)} - \frac{1}{(x - i + 1)}$$

Taking the first one:
$$ \frac{1}{(x - i - 1)} = \frac{1}{x + 1 - i - 2} = \frac{-1}{i+2}\cdot\frac{1}{1 - \dfrac{x+1}{i+2}} = \frac{-1}{i+2} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(x+1)^n}{(i+2)^n} = \\ = -\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(x+1)^n}{(i+2)^{n+1}}$$
Then the second therm, combining, then $F_2$, combining all together. Is that correct way? Just my answer looks ugly, not like wolfram alpha [shows](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+%28x%2B2%29%2F%28x%5E2%2B2x%2B2%29+at+x+%3D+-1).

Comment: That's definitely not correct for $F_1$. You've got $A,B$ wrong.

Comment: The roots of $x^2+2x+2$ are$-1+i$ and $-1-i$.

Comment: $x^2+2x+2=(x-(-1-i))(x-(-1+i))$

Comment: There's no reason to separate the $2+x$. Solve:$$\frac{2+x}{x^2+2x+2} = \frac{A}{x+1-i}+\frac{B}{x+1+i}$$

Comment: thanks, I should definetly go to sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=x+1$, then
$$\frac{2+x}{x^2+2x+2}=\frac{1+u}{1+u^2}=(1+u)(1-u^2+u^4-u^6+\cdots)$$
$$=1+u-u^2-u^3+u^4+u^5-u^6-u^7+\cdots$$
$$=1+(x+1)-(x+1)^2-(x+1)^3+(x+1)^4+\cdots.$$

Comment: Great solution.